# What is the scope of Test Coverage in Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, junit

Suppose that I have `demoServiceImpl` and `demoServiceImplTest` in the following Maven project structure.

```
|--- src    
    |--- main
        |--- java
            |--- com.demo.services
                |--- demoServiceImpl.java

    |--- test
        |--- java
            |--- com.demo.unitTest
                |--- demoServiceImplTest.java
```

In IntelliJ IDEA, there is an option called **[Packages and classes to include in coverage data](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#coverage-run-configurations)** used to narrow down the code coverage scope.

I am wondering, for example if I want to see the coverage for `demoServiceImplTest`, which packages should I add to this section? I thought that, as I wrote this `demoServiceImplTest` Unit Test for testing just `demoServiceImpl`, then it is ok to add only `demoServiceImpl` or its package to this Packages and classes to include in coverage data section. Is that true? Or what is the proper approach?

Comment: The tests are made to test your implementation. So you want to know the coverage of the implementation. If you want to see the coverage on your tests, you would need to write tests to test the testing class. That doesn't really make sense

Comment: As Unit tests are written for testing methods in a class, can we  say that we should just focus on the class and its tested methods while running coverage of its unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to move any packages.
Go to your class demoServiceImpl (btw that should be named DemoServiceImpl) inside package com.demo.services.

Then hit Ctrl + alt + T (or menu -> Navigate -> Test).
It will enter in right test class or ask you to create one to the right package with this popup :
[image: Create new test]

So, let the IDE automatically create the test class to the right package.
When you will execute with coverage It will rely on it to check covered packages, classes and methods.

Feel free to explore Injellij Documatation which is not bad at all.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html

And : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanations, voted up. I think the problem may be not creating the test class as you mentioned. But, assume that, in this case **what should be the scope** of `DemoServiceImplTest`? Should it be `DemoServiceImpl` or its container package? Because, for the other unit tests, all the **Packages and classes to include in coverage data** shows `com.demo.services` package. Does it come as default so that include the service methods to the generated coverage?

Comment: Oh, well, the scope should be com.demo.services and your package com.demo.unitTest should be named com.demo.services too.
Otherwise, your directory structure is perfect.

Comment: Yes Intellij is clever enough to find that your test cover your service implementation wherever it's package is located. (package included and excluded in configuration purpose is only to speed up coverage focalizing on your business classes)

Comment: I asked 2 questions, but do not understand which one is answered. So, could you please reply by number (same questions separated by number)? >>>

Comment: Assume that I have `DemoServiceImpl` and its unit test `DemoServiceImplTest`. In order to get coverage for this unit test, what should be the scope of DemoServiceImplTest?

Comment: **1.** Should it be DemoServiceImpl or its container package?

Comment: **2.** Maybe the only difference is when selecting container package, the result will list the coverage for all the other classes in that package. Is that true?

Comment: 1. You can either specify class or package both works.
2. Yes coverage is detailed by packages, classes, methods and even lines of code covered. Coverage just check that a test pass through that package, class, method or each line of code at execution. You don't want to compute coverage for your libraries but only your service code that's why you can include and exclude classes and packages from the scope.